# runtime error on android

Tags: java, android

```
11-25 13:20:55.263: D/AndroidRuntime(467): Shutting down VM
11-25 13:20:55.263: W/dalvikvm(467): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xample.counter/com.xample.counter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.xample.counter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  ... 11 more
```

I am new to android and having this error could not resolve it please help me out

Comment: could you post the code with which you are working.
Its clear that there is a null value which you are using but it will be clear if you post some code

Comment: If possible, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). That way we can help you more easily.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 13:20:55.313: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.xample.counter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)  We need to see your onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your MainActivity code. And put log statement in your program to debug and
AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.xample.counter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)

This line indicates check your line no. 28 in onCreate()